# Error in Defining an associative array in D

Tags: d

So I would like to implement a hash lookup for translating codons to amino acids in D. When i write

```
int[string] codon_table = [
  "ATG": 'M',
  "TTT": 'F', "TTC": 'F', "TTA": 'L',
  "TTG": 'L', "CTT": 'L', "CTC": 'L',
  "CTA": 'L', "CTG": 'L', "ATT": 'I',
  "ATC": 'I', "ATA": 'I', "GTT": 'V',
  "GTC": 'V', "GTA": 'V', "GTG": 'V',
  "TCT": 'S', "TCC": 'S', "TCA": 'S',
  "TCG": 'S', "CCT": 'P', "CCC": 'P',
  "CCA": 'P', "CCG": 'P', "ACT": 'T',
  "ACC": 'T', "ACG": 'T', "GCT": 'A',
  "GCC": 'A', "GCA": 'A', "GCG": 'A',
  "TAT": 'Y', "TAC": 'Y', "TAA": '*',
  "TAG": '*', "CAT": 'H', "CAC": 'H',
  "CAA": 'Q', "CAG": 'Q', "AAT": 'N',
  "AAC": 'N', "AAA": 'K', "AAG": 'K',
  "GAT": 'D', "GAC": 'D', "GAA": 'E',
  "GAG": 'E', "TGT": 'C', "TGC": 'C',
  "TGA": '*', "TGG": 'W', "CGT": 'R',
  "CGC": 'R', "CGA": 'R', "CGG": 'R',
  "AGT": 'S', "AGC": 'S', "AGA": 'R',
  "AGG": 'R', "GGT": 'G', "GGC": 'G',
  "GGA": 'G', "GGG": 'G'
  ];
```

The code does not compile and I get

```
Error: no-constant expression
```

I think this is slightly odd because I though it would trivial to write an associate array as a constant and use it as a lookup table. When I append enum for example;

```
enum int[string] codon_table = [...]
```

it seems to work.

What are the tradeoffs of using `enum` vs `static int[string]` when defining this sort of associative array? 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `enum int[string] codon_table` will create a new associative array every time you use it, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: that would be terrible because you can have very long DNA strings >1million characters and say you want a fast lookup table/hash to translate them to  amino acids!

Comment: This code seems to compile as is now (checked with DMD 2.071.1); making it immutable, as Colonel Thirty Two suggests in the accepted answer (no need for initialisation inside of `static this`), is probably still a good idea in this context, though.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Richard-Ambler and for following on the issue! Love the D community!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
immutable int[string] codon_table;
static this() {
    codon_table = [
        "ATG": 'M',
        // ...
        "GGA": 'G', "GGG": 'G'
    ];
}
```

I made the table immutable since it's unlikely that you're going to need to change a lookup table.

That said, it's a bit weird that your initializer doesn't work. You might want to post this on the D forums.

Comment: Global variable initializers are limited to data that can be placed in the data segment during compile-time. However AA literal may be expanded later and thus needs to be placed on heap so that it can possibly grow. This requires runtime initialization even if original expression looks pretty constant.

Comment: There is enhancement request to lift that limitation for immutable AA globals but I don't remember bugzilla ID right now.

Comment: P.S. @Colonel-Thirty-Two You don't need to `assumeUnique` in module constructors, immutability is not yet enforced at that point (http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/4986b74cf43f)